# How to add HMAC to CryptoJS AES encryption?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

CryptoJS's convenience function `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("some plaintext", "password")` doesn't seem to do any authentication.

I see CryptoJS provides an [HMAC class](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#HMAC), but I'm confused about how to use this to encrypt-then-authenticate.

I searched around for tutorials and other questions but couldn't find any.

How would I add authentication using the above CryptoJS HMAC class to authenticate the ciphertext produced by `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea with the HMAC provided by cryptoJS is to have you, the developer, pass it both the encrypted data and a key in order for it to spit out the MAC on the other end.

Below is an example of how you could use it to produce a MAC for your encrypted data. The idea here is that the *key* object is the shared secret used between you and trusted parties to verify the integrity of the encrypted data.

```
    //Encrypt Data
    var encryptObject = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(content, key, { iv: yourIV });

    //Calculate HMAC
    var HMAC = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encryptObject.toString(), key);
```

A few things to keep in mind.

- Always calculate the HMAC on the encrypted object **before** decryption. This prevents any manipulation of the encrypted data to cause harm after decryption.
- Make sure the data encoding/format is the same when validating the HMAC. For example, above I used the toString() of my encrypted object, I did this becuase cryptoJS automatically serializes that object to only be the ciphertext. Upon decryption, I calculate the HMAC on the binary string of the encrypted blob I am presented with to make sure the HMAC calculates correctly.

With that I think you should be set to validate some data!

Also for a working example, you could check out http://meowcrypt.com/ which is my in browser file encryption service for google drive that uses cryptoJS.